# Postion of argument will be fixed

Tags: python

in command line if I run my program

`python parse.py config=abc.txt factor_date=20151001 like this`

I want the position of argument will be fixed. That means if I pass argument like below

```
python parse.py factor_date=20151001 config=abc.txt
```

it has to show error.

```
import sys

config_file=sys.argv[1]
factor_date = sys.argv[2]

argstring=""+config_file+" "+factor_date+""

arg_list = argstring.split(' ')
input={}

for arg in arg_list:
    #x=arg.split("--")
    key,val=arg.split("=")[0],arg.split("=")[1]
    if key == "config":
        input[key]=val
    if key =="factor_date":
        input[key]=val
print input
```

Comment: Your arguments are optional?

Comment: Why the hell you make a `argstring` just to `.split()` it?

Comment: Add a counter to the `for` loop. Inside `if key == "factor_date"` check counter to see if it is 2.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html). Your use case is for positional arguments. If you specify the name of the argument (optional arguments with argparse) then it does not make sense to force a specific order.

Still, when using positional arguments one could call the program with worng arguments, you will have to check by yourself the values provided by the user. However, you can force a type and it will automagically convert the strings, which in the case you describe would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/). It let's you create command line interfaces pretty much effortlessly. It's bases on using decorators.